# Remove last character in a path string if it is a slash

Tags: php, regex, string, url-rewriting, character

I'm doing some url rewriting in PHP and need to find URLS with a slash at the end and then do a 301 redirect.  I thought there'd be a simple PHP function to find last string, but I couldn't find anything.  First instincts make m think I need to use regex, but I'm not 100%.

Here's one example:

http://domainx.com/characters/ I want to find a trailing slash and turn it into http://domainx.com/characters

So what function will help me check if the last character is a "/"?

Comment: There are more than 10 ways of doing this!

Comment: [`if (s($str)->endsWith('/'))`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L117) [`header('Location: '.s($str)->replaceLast('/'))`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L305), as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str). Anyway, for redirects, doing this in the web server (e.g. Apache using `mod_rewrite`) is probably easier.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

A nice solution to remove safely the last `/` is to use

```
$string = rtrim($string, '/');
```

[`rtrim()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) removes  all `/`s on the right side of the string when there is one or more.

You can also safely add exactly one single `/` at the end of an URL:

```
$string = rtrim($string, '/').'/';
```

Answer (score 33):

You can use [`substr`](http://php.net/substr):

```
substr($str, -1)
```

This returns the last byte/character in a single-byte string. See also the multi-byte string variant [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/mb_substr).

But if you just want to remove any trailing slashes, [`rtrim`](http://php.net/rtrim) is probably the best solution.

And since you’re working with URLs, you might also take a look at [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) to parse URLs as a trailing slash does not need to be part of the URL path.

Answer (score 14):

`$string[strlen($string)-1]` gives you the last character.

But if you want to strip trailing slashes, you can do `$string = rtrim($string, '/');`. If there is no trailing slash, `$string` will remain unchanged.

Comment: `substr($string,-1)` is nice :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [basename()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

This will return `characters` for `http://domainx.com/characters/` as well as `http://domainx.com/characters`

You can do like this:-

```
$page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$module = basename($page);
```

Then you can use the `$module` directly in your conditional logic without doing any redirects.

If you want to collect the last `/` trimmed URL then you can do this:-

If you are storing the project base url in a config file:-

```
BASE_URL  = 'http://example.com'
```

then you can do this:-

```
$page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$module = basename($page);
$trimmedUrl = BASE_URL.'/'.$module;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `preg_replace()` a `/` at the end of the subject

```
$url = 'http://domainx.com/characters/';
$url = preg_replace('/(?:\/)$/', '', $url);
```

Comment: The non-capturing group is not at all necessary.  `~/$~` will do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you have php > 7.1

```
$string[-1]
```

Will give you the last character

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ff439889f14906749e4eb6328796c354c60f269b

Difference between rtrim and custom function:

```
<?php

$string0 = 'hi//';
$string1 = 'hello/';
$string2 = 'world';

function untrailingslashit( $string ) {
    return $string[-1] === '/' ? substr( $string, 0, -1) : $string;
}

echo untrailingslashit($string0);
echo "\n";
echo untrailingslashit($string1);
echo "\n";
echo untrailingslashit($string2);
echo "\n";
echo rtrim($string0, "/");
```

Result:

```
hi/
hello
world
hi
```

Comment: This doesn't remove the last slash

Answer (score 0):

### With PHP 8

```
str_ends_with($string, '/');
```

---

New `str_starts_with()` and `str_ends_with()` functions are added into the core.

Comment: This doesn't remove the last slash.

Answer (score -1):

This is coming straight from WordPress:

```
function untrailingslashit( $string ) {
    return rtrim( $string, '/\\' );
}
```

Comment: [`rtrim()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4427180/2943403) was already recommended on this page.

Comment: But my solution is wrapped as a function, and it includes escaped slashes. It's also been tried and tested with millions of websites built on WordPress.

Comment: Wrapping a single, native function call in a custom function is not beneficial programming.  There is only a requirement to rtrim forward slashes in this question.  There is no call for rtrimming backslashes.