# how to know if a $string ends with ','?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Find last character in a string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427172/find-last-character-in-a-string-in-php)

How can I know if the last char of a $string is ',' ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [find last character in a string in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427172/find-last-character-in-a-string-in-php). Won't tell you if the string starts with a comma, but I take you know how to use an `if`.

Comment: [PHP Manual: string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)

Comment: While not an answer, probably the most common reason someone would ask this question is that they want to know if there is a comma they should remove; or perhaps whether they should add or a comma, or one already exists. For these cases, something like `$string = rtrim($string, ',')` is probably the simplest path: you don't NEED to know whether there's something on the end, then.

Comment: PHP 8.0 introduces new method for this job `str_end_with`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64160081/7082164

Answer (score 126, accepted):

There are a few options:

```
if (substr($string, -1) == ',') {
```

Or (slightly less readable):

```
if ($string[strlen($string) - 1] == ',') {
```

Or (even less readable):

```
if (strrpos($string, ',') == strlen($string) - 1) {
```

Or (even worse yet):

```
if (preg_match('/,$/', $string)) {
```

Or (wow this is bad):

```
if (end(explode(',', $string)) == '') {
```

The take away, is just use `substr($string, -1)` and be done with it.  But there are many other alternatives out there...

Comment: I don't think your second last one is that bad at all...

Comment: I know it's subjective, but I find the preg_match one to be the most readable

Comment: From PHP 7.1 you can use `if ($string[-1] == ',')`. It's clear and faster than using substr().

Comment: how to match like with dot in the end /.$/

Answer (score 12):

```
$string = 'foo,bar,';
if(substr($string, -1) === ','){
    // it ends with ','
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use regular expressions for this in PHP:

```
if (preg_match("/,$/", $string)) {
    #DO THIS
} else {
    #DO THAT
}
```

This says to check for a match of a comma at the end of the $string.

Comment: how to match like with dot in the end /.$/

Answer (score 4):

```
if (substr($str, -1) === ',') 
{
 echo 'it is';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For the micro optimizers:

```
$string[strlen($string)-1] == ","
```

Comment: will trigger a notice when `$string = ''` though. downvote wasnt me.

Comment: @Gordon which is quite helpful actually (depending on use case, of course)

Answer (score 2):

See the endsWith function here:

[startsWith() and endsWith() functions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/php-startswith-and-endswith-functions)

Comment: should have been a comment or a CW because we do not get reputation for finding duplicates.

Comment: Now turned into a CW :-)

Comment: there is another function for helping is str_ends_with($string, ',')
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ends-with.php

Answer (score 2):

```
//$str hold your string
if(substr($str, -1) ==',')
{
   return true
}
```