# PHP Get first array value that ends with ".jpg"

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have some arrays and they might all be formatted like so:

```
Array (
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => 151108-some_image-006.jpg
    [3] => high
    [4] => low
)
```

I know they have 5 values, but I can not be certain where each value is being placed.

I am trying to get only the image out of this array

```
$pos = array_search('*.jpg', $main_photo_directory);
echo $main_photo_directory[$pos];
```

But as we all know, it's looking for a literal `*.jpg` which it can't find.  I'm not so super at regex and wouldn't know how to format an appropriate string.

What is the best way to get the first image (assuming there may be more than one) out of this array?

**ADDITION**

One of the reasons I am asking is to find a simple way to search through an array.  I do not know regex, though I'd like to use it.  I wrote the question looking for a regex to find '.jpg' at the end of a string which no search results had yielded.

Comment: Regex??? Use a loop?

Comment: @PeeHaa  and search for what?

Comment: a string ending in .jpg

Comment: Right - there's my problem.  How do I search for a string ending in .jpg?

Comment: Just read the last four characters of each array element in a loop to see if they equal `.jpg`

Comment: aah using substring?

Comment: `substr($str,-3)=='jpg'`

Comment: I knew you guys were smart!

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764859/how-to-know-if-a-string-ends-with or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619610/whats-the-most-efficient-test-of-whether-a-php-string-ends-with-another-string

Comment: with a 2k rep i expected you could work this one out

Comment: Also possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592120/php-search-array-using-wildcard

Comment: 2k rep doesn't mean I know everything.  Most of the rep is from javascript (jQuery really)

Comment: Thanks.  So for all of the criticism on a brain fart, I guess I'll close the question.  Love this community!

Comment: nowadays, rep means nothing... the system is a bit broken

Comment: it should mean you can use google and or the sites search engine.

Comment: @dagon, Yes, I googled for 15 minutes not getting a specific answer.  The voted up answer below is what I was looking for, but I couldn't figure out the regex to place in there.

Comment: @PeeHaa:  Bad dupe.  I recommend http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592120/php-search-array-using-wildcard

Comment: ok last comment, a whole  15 minutes before asking? i would spend days - but i realise some people have a very short attention span (its that MTV right?)

Comment: @AbraCadaver which one? I just linked three

Comment: @Dagon, Yes, you're perfectly in-line to start the insults and the "I am holier than thou".  A question that took less than 3 minutes to answer and wasted 10 minutes of your time making stupid comments deserved 15 minutes of looking. - You must be bitter with 11/12 of your questions having down votes.

Comment: @PeeHaa: The question was only marked as a dupe of _startsWith() and endsWith() functions in PHP_.  Not the best one IMHO.

Comment: @PeeHaa I like the one that AbraCadaver mentioned

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
echo current(preg_grep('/\.jpg$/', $array));
```

Comment: Cleanest, simplest, most straight forward answer.  Thank you. - Will accept in 7 minutes

Comment: Indeed, impressive. You only have to take care how to use the result, since you cannot simply use `current()` in function calls, for example.

Comment: @arkascha That's fine, I am using the literal string to push back through an ajax call.  What has been supplied works perfectly for my needs.

Comment: @arkascha: What?  Why not? `echo strtoupper(current(preg_grep('/\.jpg$/', $array)));`

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the array until you find a string ending in jpg:

```
function endsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    return $needle === "" || (($temp = strlen($haystack) - strlen($needle)) >= 0 && strpos($haystack, $needle, $temp) !== FALSE);
}

$array = [];
$result = false;
foreach($array as $img) {
  if(endsWith($img, '.jpg')) {
    $result = $img;
    break;
  }
}

echo $result;
```