# How to get position of last character in a string?

Tags: php, strpos

For example, I have `$string = "abc+def"`, how can i get position of 'f'? Is it possible of finding position of last character in the string, in the above example, 'f' is last character.

Comment: I didn't clearly understand your question but i think what you need is to count the number of your string in order to get the position of the last character.
<?php
$text = 'abc+def';
echo strlen($text); 
?>

Comment: what? you're looking the last position of `f` or position of the final string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find last character in a string in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427172/find-last-character-in-a-string-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP, as in most languages with zero-based indexing, the index of the last character in a string will be one less than the length of the string (`strlen($string) - 1`).

Comment: Edited - in PHP, the length function is `strlen`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the last character, just use `strlen()` the length - 1. Its starts at zero.

```
echo (strlen($string)-1); // 6
echo $string[strlen($string)-1]; // f
```

It has a total of 7 characters, but positions start at zero.

Answer (score 0):

**I use this code to find charater in string. I hope this helpful**

```
$string = 'abc+def';
$stringcheck = 'f';
$stringSP = str_split($string);
$position = NULL;
foreach ($stringSP as $key => $value){
    if(strcasecmp($stringcheck,$value) == 0){
       $position = $key + 1;
    }
}
```